# gcc/mingw/windows: -l option only work when specified at the end of the line

Tags: gcc, mingw

My problem is the following:

I have the small program below (see file conftest.c).

(1) If i compile conftest.c like this (with -l at the end):

gcc -o conftest conftest.c -lintl

it compiles fine.

(2) But if i compile conftest.c like this (with -l at the end):

gcc -o conftest -lintl conftest.c

compilation fails with error :
C:\Users\devel\AppData\Local\Temp\cce00i8m.o:conftest.c:(.text+0x16): référence indéfinie vers « *imp*_libintl_gettext »
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.

I am using mingw with gcc 4.5.0 under windows. gcc is installed in /mingw/bin

It seems that the order of the -l options pass to gcc has an importance. This is very annoying because i am trying to install the Bundle::Gnome2 of ActiveState perl and it uses the (2) construct. Does anyone have any clue of how to fix this and make the (2) works?

Thanks by advance,

---

conftest.c:

```
#include <libintl.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *x = gettext("foo");return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should think of the linker command line as being processed from left to right so that earlier listed items are processed first.

And `-lXYZ` library specifications will only be used to satisfy currently unresolved references.

In other words:

```
gcc -o conftest -lintl conftest.c
```

won't actually *have* any unresolved references when it encounters `-lintl` (other than `main` of course). If you use:

```
gcc -o conftest conftest.c -lintl
```

then, at the point where `-lintl` is encountered, you *will* have unresolved references, all those used but not defined in `conftest.c`.

The usual solution is to make sure you list all library specifications *after* other object/source files.

You can also use the `-u <symbol>` option to pretend the symbol `<symbol>` is undefined, so that the library will be bought in regardless.

I'd prefer to fix the order myself, and I've never really understood why `gcc` just didn't batch up the library specifications and just keep looking until either all symbols were satisfied or no more possibly could (or at least provie that as an option).

In your case, you can just use something like:

```
gcc -o conftest -u gettext -lintl conftest.c
```

And you can specify more `-u` options for each symbol you want to pretend is undefined (i.e., to bring in as many libraries as required).

Answer (score 0):

The gcc has a closure mode in which it will scan the provided libraries ad nauseam, just as paxdiablo described. It works with --start-group and --end-group, like

```
gcc -o conftest --start-group -lintl conftest.c --end-group
```

To quote the manual: "Using this option has a significant performance cost.  It is best to use it only when there are unavoidable circular references between two or more archives."